# Node.js process hangs on SIGTERM if a DNS resolution is in progress

Tags: node.js, dns, signals, gethostbyname

I am using node 10.38 on Linux (Ubuntu 4.10, FC20, etc...).

I have some code in startup which looks like:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  process.exit(1);
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  process.exit(1);
});
```

Somewhere else in the process, I have code like this:

```
dns.lookup("somehostname", function(err, addresses, family) {
    // do something
});
```

Many times, if you send SIGTERM to the process, node will not quit. It will hang for as long as it takes to resolve DNS. Sometimes, if DNS server does not respond, it can take up to 5 minutes to quit. If you take a GDB stack trace at this time, you see a stack trace like this. If you attach a gdb debugger, you will see that it is stuck in trying to resolve the hostname we are trying to resolve.

I would have thought that gethostbyname can be interrupted by signals. Can someone shed some insight into it?

```
Thread 3 (process 18074):
#0  0x00007fabac3bed26 in poll () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007fababcdce90 in __libc_res_nsend () from /lib64/libresolv.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007fababcdbcb6 in __libc_res_nquery () from /lib64/libresolv.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007fababcdbf27 in __libc_res_nquerydomain () from /lib64/libresolv.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007fababcdc14b in __libc_res_nsearch () from /lib64/libresolv.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007fababeeb8ef in _nss_dns_gethostbyname3_r () from 
/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007fababeebb64 in _nss_dns_gethostbyname2_r () from 
/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007fabac3b02bf in gaih_inet () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007fabac3b178e in getaddrinfo () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x0000000000a0cbb2 in uv_getaddrinfo ()
No symbol table info available.
#10 0x0000000000a127c4 in uv_queue_work ()
No symbol table info available.
#11 0x0000000000a08462 in uv_thread_create ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Answer (score 0):

`gethostbyname` can indeed be interrupted by signals, but you'll see right at the bottom of the stack trace that the call is being made within a thread.

The `SIGTERM` that you send is only being delivered to the main program and for reasons I didn't yet establish the process isn't exiting until all threads have completed their work.

Comment: But if main program calls "process.exit(0)", shouldn't entire process quit?